# aws deploying ML model

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've locally implemented an ML model that I need to deploy on S3 and then creating a Lambda in order to invoke it.

The problem is that I'm facing tons of errors. I've tried to read the documentation and follow some notebooks, but I can't figure how to make my model working out.

Here is the code:

```
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
import sagemaker
import argparse
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.externals import joblib
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
import datetime as dt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
import io
from sagemaker.sklearn.estimator import SKLearn
import s3fs


prefix = 'FP'
sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
role = get_execution_role()

data = pd.read_csv("df.csv", header = 0, usecols = ["col1", "col2"])


os.makedirs('./data_DM', exist_ok=True)
data.to_csv('./data_DM/orders.csv')

WORK_DIRECTORY = 'data_DM'

train_input = sagemaker_session.upload_data(WORK_DIRECTORY, key_prefix="{}/{}".format(prefix, WORK_DIRECTORY) )


script_path = './data_DM/My_script.py'

sklearn = SKLearn(
    entry_point=script_path,
    train_instance_type="ml.m5.2xlarge",
    role=role,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)

sklearn.fit({'train': train_input})
```

And here the My_script.py:

```
import argparse
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.externals import joblib
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
import datetime as dt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
import io
from sklearn import tree
import boto3, re, sys, math, json, urllib.request

def cleaning(data):
     lots of cleaning
     return cleaned data


if __name__ =='__main__':
    
    bucket_name = 'ciao'
    file_name = 'df.csv 


    data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, file_name)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('--output-data-dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_OUTPUT_DATA_DIR'])
    parser.add_argument('--model-dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_MODEL_DIR'])
    parser.add_argument('--train', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN'])

    args = parser.parse_args()

    data = pd.read_csv(data_location, header = 0, usecols = ["col1", "col2"])

    data_ml = cleaning(data) 

    y = data_ml.loc[:,"event"]
    X = data_ml.loc[:, data_ml.columns != 'event']

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
    
    

    model =  tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(n_estimators=600, class_weight = "balanced", random_state=42)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    #Save the model to the location specified by args.model_dir
    joblib.dump(model, os.path.join(args.model_dir, "model.joblib"))



def model_fn(model_dir):
    model = joblib.load(os.path.join(model_dir, "model.joblib"))
    return model


def input_fn(request_body, request_content_type):
    if request_content_type == 'text/csv':
        samples = []
        for r in request_body.split('|'):
            samples.append(list(map(float,r.split(','))))
        return np.array(samples)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Thie model only supports text/csv input")

def predict_fn(input_data, model):
    return model.predict_proba(cleaning(input_data))

def output_fn(prediction, content_type):
    return ' | '.join([INDEX_TO_LABEL[t] for t in prediction])
```

Now the error is the following:

```
/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py:47: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
import imp
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"main", mod_spec)
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/opt/ml/code/Failure_Pred.py", line 206, in
"weight", "userPrice", "amount", "nParcel"])
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 440, in _read
filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 206, in get_filepath_or_buffer
from pandas.io import s3
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/s3.py", line 10, in
"s3fs", extra="The s3fs package is required to handle s3 files."
File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/_optional.py", line 93, in import_optional_dependency
raise ImportError(message.format(name=name, extra=extra)) from None
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 's3fs'. The s3fs package is required to handle s3 files. Use pip or conda to install s3fs.
2020-07-09 12:13:27,645 sagemaker-containers ERROR ExecuteUserScriptError:
Command "/miniconda3/bin/python -m Failure_Pred"

2020-07-09 12:13:36 Uploading - Uploading generated training model
2020-07-09 12:13:36 Failed - Training job failed

Error for Training job sagemaker-scikit-learn-2020-07-09-12-10-17-446: Failed. Reason: AlgorithmError: ExecuteUserScriptError:
Command "/miniconda3/bin/python -m Failure_Pred"
```

It seems that I don't have installed s3fs, but I've already installed it both via pip install and via conda install.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: import `s3fs` in `My_script.py`.

Comment: already tried, it doesn't work: "no module named s3fs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*edit 07/10: adding the training key in the local reading path:
replacing
`opt/ml/input/data/orders.csv` by `opt/ml/input/data/train/orders.csv`*

You have an error because your `data = pd.read_csv(data_location, ...)` tries to read from S3. Try replacing by `data = pd.read_csv('opt/ml/input/data/orders.csv', ...)`

If you use SageMaker, **you do not need to read from S3 inside your training script: SageMaker does the copy from S3 to EC2 for you**.

Instead, as indicated in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-training-algo-running-container.html#your-algorithms-training-algo-running-container-inputdataconfig), you only need to read the data from the **local** path `opt/ml/input/data/<channel name>` where `<channel name>` is the key used to name your input in the training call `model.fit({'<channel name>': 's3://my data'})`.  Note that local here means local to the remote ephemeral SageMaker Training EC2 instance, not to the SageMaker Notebook EC2 instance you may be using for development and orchestration.

Same thing with the artifact copy to s3: you do not need to do it yourself. Just write the artifact in the local path `opt/ml/model`, and the service will copy it back to S3. Some AWS-provided containers (like the sklearn container) also provide input data path and artefact path in environment variable(`SM_CHANNEL_<channel name>` and `SM_MODEL_DIR`), which you can optionally use to avoid hard-coding them in your code. You can get inspiration from [this random forest demo](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_randomforest/Sklearn_on_SageMaker_end2end.ipynb) and adapt it to your case. You do not need s3fs.

Comment: Hey Olivier, thanks for your help. Unfortunately it raises a file not found error. I've tried different paths as well but nothing

Comment: right, sorry my path was wrong, it needs to include channel name: `pd.read_csv('opt/ml/input/data/train/orders.csv', ...)`

Comment: basically, if you use `sklearn.fit({'mylittlechannel': train_input})` to launch the job, inside your script you must read from `opt/ml/input/data/mylittlechannel/...`

Comment: By following the random forest demo I was able to fix the problem, even by reading from s3. Thanks!